# What are these sarXX files?

Tags: centos, logs, sar

I know what are the saXX files in /var/log/sa directory but can you tell me what are the sa"**r**"XX files please?

```
[root@centos3 sa]# ll
total 3104
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  43648 19 janv. 16:00 sa19
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 123796 22 janv. 23:50 sa22
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 460832 23 janv. 23:50 sa23
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 451340 24 janv. 23:50 sa24
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 447228 25 janv. 22:40 sa25
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 170128 26 janv. 18:00 sa26
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 105332 29 janv. 17:00 sa29
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 126804 30 janv. 23:50 sa30
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 220448 31 janv. 13:10 sa31
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 124563 22 janv. 23:53 sar22
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 378595 23 janv. 23:53 sar23
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 380539 24 janv. 23:53 sar24
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 120823 30 janv. 23:53 sar30
```

I'm on CentOS 6.9.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/sa2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers in the file name normally represent the data for that specific day on the month.

You can extract the data from the files with:

```
sar -f <filename>
```

The sa files are data files that can only be read an interrogated using the sar package. The sar files are just ASCII files that can be read with something like cat.

Comment: I can do `sar -f saXX` but it doesn't work with `sar -f sa"r"XX`

Comment: Why are you adding r? Do you mean -r?

Comment: See my files listed above. Some have a "r" in their name other don't. For example "sa22" and "sar22". I know now thanks to @Kusalananda that "sa2" generates these files (reports) but I don't know how to read them.

Comment: The sar files are just ascii files. You should be able to read them with cat.

Comment: You are right thanks. Maybe you can edit your answer because it doesn't answer my question about these files but about saXX files.

Comment: I've amended the answer accordingly..